# How to manipulate fetch response for single object JSON in react-native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am creating my first mobile app using react-native. I am using axios to fetch data from a wordpress website.

I managed to successfully get data from an array JSON with a list of musical tracks. I then inserted data into a `state` variable. Then, I used `.map` function to show contents on screen. Here's a working sample code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FreshTracks extends Component {
    state={tracks:[]}
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("https://<URL for JSON list of tracks>")
            .then(response => this.setState({tracks:response.data}))
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Fetch error: ' + error.message);
                });
    }  
    renderTracks(){
        return this.state.tracks.map (track =>
            <View key={track.id}>
                <Text>{track.title.rendered}</Text>
                <Text>{track.content.rendered}</Text>
            </View>
        )  
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>    
                {this.renderTracks()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I am struggling to get data from a single object JSON, one musical track.

At first, I tried keeping the same code, only changing the url. I get `Fetch error: this.state.tracks.map is not a function`. I tried `console.log(this.state.tracks)` before the `return` in `renderTracks()` and the data is returned in the console as an object, exactly how it should.

I then tried to change the `state` initialization to: `state={tracks:*{}*}` instead of `state={tracks:*[]*}`. Also, i changed the `renderTracks()` function to:

```
renderTracks(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.tracks.id}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.tracks.slug}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.tracks.title.rendered}</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.tracks.content.rendered}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

This way is partially working  Accessing data on a single level like `this.state.tracks.id` or `this.state.tracks.slug` is working as expected. Accessing multi-level data like `this.state.tracks.title.rendered` throws an error:

```
Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined
```

What should I do to correctly get data from single object JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JSON object doesn't have a `map()` method. So your code that assumed `this.state.tracks` is an array would crash.

Instead, you want to keep `this.state.track` as `null` at first, and then fill it in with an object. Don't forget to check for `null` in render and show some kind of a placeholder.

Something like this will probably work?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class FreshTracks extends Component {
  state = {track: null};

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("https://<your URL for a single track>")
         .then(response => this.setState({track:response.data}))
         .catch(function(error) {
           console.log('Fetch error: ' + error.message);
         });
  }  

  render() {
    const track = this.state.track;
    if (track === null) {
      return <View><Text>Loading...</Text></View>;
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{track.title.rendered}</Text>
        <Text>{track.content.rendered}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked, indeed. I have actually tried defining `track` as `null` before, but did not check for `null` in render, so it was throwing `Cannot read property 'title' of null` 
Thank you!